# What's wrong with this code for BinarySearch?

Tags: python, binary-search

This is the python Binary Search code and when I run it doesn't work.

```
# Binary Search

def BinarySearch(*args, key, size):
    low = 0
    high = size - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) / 2
        if key < args[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            if key > args[mid]:
                low = mid + 1
            else:
                return mid + 1
    return -1

arraySize = 10
A = [num * 2 for num in range(10)]
print("Numbers in array are : ", A)
searchKey = input("Enter integer search key : ")
element = BinarySearch(A, searchKey, arraySize)
if element != -1:
    print("Found value in element : ", element)
else:
    print("Value not found.")
```

The error is like this:

> TypeError: BinarySearch() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'key' and 'size'
>   So, What's wrong with it?Please help:)

Comment: What's the point in using `args`? `def binary_search(lst, target)` should be sufficient. Lists (not arrays, here) already have a `len()` property you can use which is more reliable than hardcoding it like in C.

Comment: You put `*args` in your function parameters for some reason. That eats up all the positional arguments. That means any subsequent arguments have to be keyword arguments.

Comment: pass your required positional arguments before the *args in your function `def BinarySearch(key, size, *args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your program.

1. You have to place the *args and **args after the positional and keyword
     arguements.
2. Lets say you have  modified the function definition. Now it will convert 
     the array into a tuple which won't work either as per your
   algo.it wil convert the list to tuple of lists.

   ```
       def BinarySearch( key, size,*args):
             pass

       [] -> ([], )
   ```

3.So, you need to place only the array part.Refer the below code.

```
    # Binary Search

def BinarySearch(arr, key, size):
    print(args)
    low = 0
    high = size - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if key < args[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            if key > args[mid]:
                low = mid + 1
            else:
                return mid + 1
    return -1

arraySize = 10
A = [num * 2 for num in range(10)]
print("Numbers in array are : ", A)
searchKey = input("Enter integer search key : ")
element = BinarySearch(A, int(searchKey), arraySize)
if element != -1:
    print("Found value in element : ", element)
else:
    print("Value not found.")
```

Comment: But Why we should call the list after variables?

Comment: I've found the problem, the problem is in division . I should use "//" instead of "/" but why?

Comment: @coderboy, '/' results a decimal value, not a integer while '//' results a nearest ineger value

Comment: Thank you so much tedd. I understood.:)

Comment: @coderboy, happy to help you.please mark it as answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
element = BinarySearch(A, searchKey, arraySize)
```

to

```
element = BinarySearch(A, key=searchKey, size=arraySize)
```